# How to cleanup threads once they have finished in Perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a Perl script that launches threads while a certain expression is verified.

```
while ($launcher == 1) {
    # do something
    push @threads, threads ->create(\&proxy, $parameters);
    push @threads, threads ->create(\&ping, $parameters);
    push @threads, threads ->create(\&dns, $parameters);
    # more threads
    foreach (@threads) {
    $_->join();
    }
}
```

The first cycle runs fine but at the second one the script exits with the following error:

> Thread already joined at launcher.pl line 290.
>   Perl exited with active threads:
>   1 running and unjoined
>   0 finished and unjoined
>   0 running and detached

I guess I shall clean @threads but how can I do that? I am not even sure if this is the problem.

Comment: It might not be your only problem, but that would definitely be a problem. The first time through the loop you join `@threads[0..2]`. Then you try to join `@threads[0..5]`, of which three threads have already been joined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just clear `@threads` at the end of the loop:

```
@threads = ();
```

Or better, declare `@threads` with `my` at the beginning of the loop:

```
while ($launcher == 1) {
    my @threads;
```

Comment: I guess you put it more elegantly than me. There's a typo in one of your mentions of `@threads` though.

Comment: That actually worked! I don't know why but I thought it was much more difficult than that lol, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to create the array inside the while loop (`while {my @threads; ...}`), unless you need it anywhere else. Otherwise you could just `@threads = ()` or `@threads = undef` at the end of the while loop.

You could also set a variable `my $next_thread;` outside the while loop and then assign `$next_thread = @threads` first thing in the while loop and change your `foreach` loop to

```
for my $index ($next_thread .. $#threads) {
    $threads[$index]->join();
}
```

or skip that and just loop over a slice of the last three added threads

```
for (@threads[-3..-1) {
    $_->join();
}
```